# How to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ from $x^3y^6 = (x+y)^9$ using implicit differentiation?

Tags: calculus

How to find $$dy/dx$$ from $$x^3y^6 = (x+y)^9$$ using implicit differentiation? I tried solving but I ended up with solution that does not agree with my textbook answer. How can I get $$dy/dx = y/x$$?

Comment: Can you write how you got the solution that does not agree with your textbook answer?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put significant work into the problem. Be aware that implicit differentiation problems are notorious for giving multiple correct different-looking answers that depend on the method of solution. Please show us your method and we'll let you know if it is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer does appear to be correct.  Here's how to go about it:

1) First, use implicit differentiation to get 
$$
3x^2y^6+6x^3y^5\frac{dy}{dx}=9(x+y)^8\left(1+\frac{dy}{dx}\right).
$$

2) Solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to get
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{9(x+y)^8-3x^2y^6}{6x^3y^5-9(x+y)^8}.
$$

3) Multiply the numerator and denominator of the RHS by $(x+y)$ to get
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{9(x+y)^9-3x^2y^6(x+y)}{6x^3y^5(x+y)-9(x+y)^9}.
$$

4) Using the original formula for $(x+y)^9$, this becomes 
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{9x^3y^6-3x^2y^6(x+y)}{6x^3y^5(x+y)-9x^3y^6}.
$$

5) By simplifying, we get
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{6x^3y^6-3x^2y^7}{6x^4y^5-3x^3y^6}=\frac{2xy-y^2}{2x^2-xy}.
$$

6) By factoring common factors, we get
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y(2x-y)}{x(2x-y)}=\frac{y}{x}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

**First simplify your equation by taking the cube root of each side** to get

$$xy^2=(x+y)^3$$

Then take the derivative of both sides and do the usual process to find

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{3(x+y)^2-y^2}{2xy-3(x+y)^2}$$

Then multiplying numerator and denominator by $x+y$,

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{3(x+y)^3-y^2(x+y)}{2xy(x+y)-3(x+y)^2}$$
$$=\frac{3xy^2-xy^2-y^3}{2x^2y+2xy^2-3xy^2}$$
$$=\frac{2xy-y^3}{2x^2y-xy^2}$$
$$=\frac{y^2(2-y)}{xy(2-y)}$$
$$=\frac yx$$

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $y=y(x)$ and derive your equality with respect to $x$; you will get

$$3x^2 y^6 + x^3 6y^5 y' = 9(x+y)^8 (1+y')$$

whence you immediately obtain

$$ y' = \frac {3(x+y)^8 - x^2 y^6} {2x^3 y^5 - 3(x+y)^8} .$$

Now multiply both the numerator and the denominator by $(x+y)$ and replace the terms $(x+y)^9$ by $x^3 y^6$. Simplify and you will obtain $\frac y x$.

Comment: But the OP asks how you can get the answer $y/x$, which does seem to be a correct answer.

Comment: $$xy^2 = (x+y)^3 $$

$$xy^2 = x^3 + y^3 + 3x^2y + 3xy^2 $$
$$ x^3 + y^3 + 3x^2y + 2xy^2 =0$$
$$3x^2 + 3y^2 dy/dx + 6xy + 3x^2 dy/dx + 4xydy/dx+ 2y^2 = 0$$

$$dy/dx = (3x^2 + 2y^2 + 6xy)/(3x^2 +3y^2 + 4xy) $$

Comment: @RoryDaulton: I have expanded my answer.

Comment: Tanks. Could anyone tell me Where did I go wrong?

Comment: @Pzoc99: By expanding $(x+y)^3$ you lost the possibility of later using $(x+y)^3 = x y^2$ to simplify your expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of seeing that it must be the right answer without having to do very much computation.

If $x=0$ and $x^3y^6 = (x+y)^9$ then $y=0$.

If $x \neq 0$ and $x^3y^6 = (x+y)^9$ then dividing by $x^9$ we obtain $(y/x)^6 = (1+y/x)^9$ so $y/x$ is a root of $(1+t)^9 - t^6$.

Conversely, if $(1+t)^9 - t^6$ and $y = tx$ then $x^3y^6 = (x+y)^9$.

It follows that set of points that satisfy $x^3y^6 = (x+y)^9$ is a union of finitely many lines passing through the origin and therefore at any point on this curve apart from the origin $dy/dx = y/x$.